# Dynamic wordpress background Based on Slider images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, nivo-slider

I am using nivoSlider on wordpress and I want the background of my homepage to change based on the current slide image!
I have no experience in javascript nor jquery but im good in php / html5 / css3.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [WordPress nivo slider](http://dev7studios.com/products/nivo-slider-wordpress-plugin/) does not have the ability to edit callbacks on slider change (unless you edit the plugin, thus breaking compatibility with future versions). But the [general jQuery plugin](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider) allows you  to do just that. You would do something like this when setting up the slider:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    // [snip]
    afterChange: function(){
        // Get the currently active image
        var active_image = $(".nivo-controlNav .active");
        // Change the class on your element and style that element with CSS
        // E.g. by fetching some attribute with $(active_image).attr()
    },
    // [snip]
});
```